# Not being able to edit an element top/left css attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, I need to hide a duplicated entry when the 'All sectors' filter is selected but and drag the last entry to cover up the hole it leaves. I made this snippet of code below to do the described action. But it only  works when ran from the browser console, it seems to ignore my instructions when put into the js file. I tried putting it in different places throughout the document but i've had no luck so far.

Snippet:

```
if (window.location.hash == '' || window.location.hash == '#'){
            accuGroup = $('a[href*="/en/company/accurate-group/"]').parent().hide()
            topval = accuGroup.css('top');
            leftval = accuGroup.css('left');
            lastArticle = $('article:last-child')
            lastArticle.css('top', topval);
            lastArticle.css('left', leftval);
        } else {
            accuGroup = $('a[href*="/en/company/accurate-group/"]').parent().show()
        }
```

You can find a live version here: https://novacap.test.whynotblue.com/en/company/

Additionally, you can find the entirety of the Javascript document here:
https://novacap.test.whynotblue.com/js/main.js?202203021656

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You might have better luck allowing the elements to position themselves instead of hardcoding top/left.  eg if they are `float:left` then when you hide the first, the others/second will automatically reposition to fill the gap.  Depends on your layout etc, so may not be a simple change.

Comment: Try wrapping your code inside doc.ready `$(()=> { .. your code .. });`  *edit* bit the bullet and looked at your site - the top/left positions are being finalised long after page load.  You'll either need a `setTimeout` and get the "FOUC" of a gap until it runs, hook into whatever causes the reposition (again "FOUC") as it positions, then repositions (won't be nice) or fix it with a better solution such as how the articles are generated in the first place.